# Probability of Picking Yellow Balls (that makes up at least 1% of total bals)

Tags: probability

Imagine there are n balls. At least 1% of the balls are yellow, and no more than 99% of the balls are white.

k number of balls are chosen from the bag, one at a time.

Each time a ball is picked, you replace each ball in the bag after you look at it. For what value of k is it true that you will see a yellow ball with at least 99% probability?

Note: It's the 'At least' part that throws me off. I'm not sure how to handle inequality in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_k$ denote the probability of seeing a yellow ball by $k$ pickings.

Then $1-p_k\leq 0.99^{k}$ or equivalently $p_k\geq1-0.99^{k}$.

So the question is: for what $k$ do we have $1-0.99^{k}\geq0.99$?

The equalities guarantee that we will have $p_k\geq0.99$.

Answer (score 0):

It is asking what is the smallest $k$ such that when $k$ balls are selected and the proportion of yellow balls is $p_y\ge 0.01$ that:
$$p(\text{1 or more of the k are yellow})\ge 0.99$$
Which is equivalent to the probability that they are not all white being greater than $0.99$:
$$
1-(1-p_y)^k \ge 0.99
$$
and the left hand side is minimised at the minimum allowed value of $p_y$. so you have to find the minimum $k \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that:
$$
1-0.99^k \ge 0.99
$$